# Read a large JSON file with Python Dask raises a delimiter error

Tags: python, dask

I try to read a JSON file of size ~12GB. I downloaded from the AMiner Citation Network dataset V12 [from here](https://www.aminer.org/citation). This is a sample, where I removed a couple of fields that makes the JSON too long.

```
[{"id":1091,"authors":[{"name":"Makoto Satoh","org":"Shinshu University","id":2312688602},{"name":"Ryo Muramatsu","org":"Shinshu University","id":2482909946},{"name":"Mizue Kayama","org":"Shinshu University","id":2128134587},{"name":"Kazunori Itoh","org":"Shinshu University","id":2101782692},{"name":"Masami Hashimoto","org":"Shinshu University","id":2114054191},{"name":"Makoto Otani","org":"Shinshu University","id":1989208940},{"name":"Michio Shimizu","org":"Nagano Prefectural College","id":2134989941},{"name":"Masahiko Sugimoto","org":"Takushoku University, Hokkaido Junior College","id":2307479915}],"title":"Preliminary Design of a Network Protocol Learning Tool Based on the Comprehension of High School Students: Design by an Empirical Study Using a Simple Mind Map","year":2013,"n_citation":1,"page_start":"89","page_end":"93","doc_type":"Conference","publisher":"Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg","volume":"","issue":"","doi":"10.1007/978-3-642-39476-8_19","references":[2005687710,2018037215],"fos":[{"name":"Telecommunications network","w":0.45139},{"name":"Computer science","w":0.45245},{"name":"Mind map","w":0.5347},{"name":"Humanâcomputer interaction","w":0.47011},{"name":"Multimedia","w":0.46629},{"name":"Empirical research","w":0.49737},{"name":"Comprehension","w":0.47042},{"name":"Communications protocol","w":0.51907}],"venue":{"raw":"International Conference on Human-Computer Interaction","id":1127419992,"type":"C"}}
,{"id":1388,"authors":[{"name":"Pranava K. Jha","id":2718958994}],"title":"Further Results on Independence in Direct-Product Graphs.","year":2000,"n_citation":1,"page_start":"","page_end":"","doc_type":"Journal","publisher":"","volume":"56","issue":"","doi":"","fos":[{"name":"Graph","w":0.0},{"name":"Discrete mathematics","w":0.45872},{"name":"Combinatorics","w":0.4515},{"name":"Direct product","w":0.59104},{"name":"Mathematics","w":0.42784}],"venue":{"raw":"Ars Combinatoria","id":73158690,"type":"J"}}
,{"id":1674,"authors":[{"name":"G. Beale","org":"Archaeological Computing Research Group, University of Southampton, UK#TAB#","id":2103626414},{"name":"G. Earl","org":"Archaeological Computing Research Group, University of Southampton, UK#TAB#","id":2117665592}],"title":"A methodology for the physically accurate visualisation of roman polychrome statuary","year":2011,"n_citation":1,"page_start":"137","page_end":"144","doc_type":"Conference","publisher":"Eurographics Association","volume":"","issue":"","doi":"10.2312/VAST/VAST11/137-144","references":[1535888970,1992876689,1993710814,2035653341,2043970887,2087778487,2094478046,2100468662,2110331535,2120448006,2138624212,2149970020,2150266006,2296384428,2403283736],"fos":[{"name":"Statue","w":0.40216},{"name":"Engineering drawing","w":0.43427},{"name":"Virtual reconstruction","w":0.0},{"name":"Computer science","w":0.42062},{"name":"Visualization","w":0.4595},{"name":"Polychrome","w":0.4474},{"name":"Artificial intelligence","w":0.40496}],"venue":{"raw":"International Conference on Virtual Reality","id":2754954274,"type":"C"}}]
```

When I try to read the file with Python Dask (I cannot open it like any other file since it's too big and I get a memory limit error)

```
import dask.bag as db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = db.read_text('dblp.v12.json').map(json.loads)
    print(b.take(4))
```

I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter
```

I checked the sample above in an online validator and it passes. So, I guess it's not an error in JSON, but something on Dask and how I should read the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like dask is passing each line of your file separately to `json.loads`. I've removed the line breaks from your sample and was able to load the data.

Of course, doing that for your entire file and sending a single JSON object to `json.loads` would defeat the purpose of using dask.

One possible solution (though I'm not sure how scalable it is for very large files) is to use `jq` to convert your JSON file into JSON lines -- by writing each element of your root JSON array into a single line in a file:

```
jq -c '.[]' your.json > your.jsonl
```

Then you can load it with dask:

```py
import dask.bag as db
import json
json_file = "your.jsonl"
b = db.read_text(json_file).map(json.loads)
print(b.take(4))
```

Comment: In `jq` or dask? Is the issue that the data is too large?